# show data from nested JSON array

Tags: angularjs, json

how to show "city" from this JSON file through angularJS http:

```
{"ers":{"resMessage":"1","response":"Success","data":{"alarms":[{"id":"1","alarm_id":"2","title":"Fire","description":"fire","type":"Fire","priority":"High","address":"Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh, India","city":"Kanpur","state":"UP","country":"India","zipcode":"123456","lattitude":"26.449923","longitude":"80.3318736"},{"id":"3","alarm_id":"4","title":"test-02","description":"test-02","type":"Medical","priority":"High","address":"Borivali West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India","city":"Mumbai","state":"MH","country":"India","zipcode":"123456","lattitude":"19.2461644","longitude":"72.85090560000003"}]}}}
```

Comment: give preference to the answers posted on time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Call url and get json data in $scope.data variable and use ng repeat in your template

**Step 2:**

Use angular for each for get city in controller

Refer following example

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = {
 "ers": {
  "resMessage": "1",
  "response": "Success",
  "data": {
   "alarms": [{
    "id": "1",
    "alarm_id": "2",
    "title": "Fire",
    "description": "fire",
    "type": "Fire",
    "priority": "High",
    "address": "Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh, India",
    "city": "Kanpur",
    "state": "UP",
    "country": "India",
    "zipcode": "123456",
    "lattitude": "26.449923",
    "longitude": "80.3318736"
   }, {
    "id": "3",
    "alarm_id": "4",
    "title": "test-02",
    "description": "test-02",
    "type": "Medical",
    "priority": "High",
    "address": "Borivali West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "state": "MH",
    "country": "India",
    "zipcode": "123456",
    "lattitude": "19.2461644",
    "longitude": "72.85090560000003"
   }]
  }
 }
};

angular.forEach($scope.data.ers.data.alarms, function(value) {
  console.log(value.city)
});

          
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="obj in data.ers.data.alarms">
   City:- {{obj.city}}<br>
   Address:- {{obj.address}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat over **`myData.ers.data.alarms`**

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.myData = {"ers":{"resMessage":"1","response":"Success","data":{"alarms":[{"id":"1","alarm_id":"2","title":"Fire","description":"fire","type":"Fire","priority":"High","address":"Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh, India","city":"Kanpur","state":"UP","country":"India","zipcode":"123456","lattitude":"26.449923","longitude":"80.3318736"},{"id":"3","alarm_id":"4","title":"test-02","description":"test-02","type":"Medical","priority":"High","address":"Borivali West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India","city":"Mumbai","state":"MH","country":"India","zipcode":"123456","lattitude":"19.2461644","longitude":"72.85090560000003"}]}}};

          
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in myData.ers.data.alarms">
  <h1> {{data.city}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```